# getXml() is running out of memory when reading large XML on low-end devices

Tags: android, xml

I have an application running on Android 2.2.2 and it's running out of memory when trying to read a somewhat large (~500kb) XML file.

The XML file is located at /res/xml, and it's read like this (in a simplified manner):

```
XmlResourceParser xmlParser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.myxml);
```

This runs perfectly on most devices (although it does take a few seconds to complete). I'm testing against a low-end device (a Huawei M835), however, and it appears to run out of memory when trying to load that.. it never finishes that call.

The error I get is not very helpful - it's just a big dump with no proper stack trace or anything. Here's my full logcat response once I execute the above line:

```
DEBUG(1700): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
DEBUG(1700): Build fingerprint: 'Huawei/M835/hwm835/M835:2.2.2/HuaweiM835/C177B622:user/release-keys'
DEBUG(1700): pid: 2798, tid: 2798  >>> com.mypackage.MyApplication <<<
DEBUG(1700): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
DEBUG(1700):  r0 46a95008  r1 00000000  r2 0011ce24  r3 00000018
DEBUG(1700):  r4 0013e8f0  r5 00000000  r6 a8125a48  r7 0011ce24
DEBUG(1700):  r8 beebc460  r9 4166ebc0  10 416ae1c0  fp 4166ebbc
DEBUG(1700):  ip 80000000  sp beebc3e8  lr a8119b8b  pc afd0f110  cpsr a0000010
DEBUG(1700):          #00  pc 0000f110  /system/lib/libc.so
DEBUG(1700):          #01  pc 00019b88  /system/lib/libutils.so
DEBUG(1700):          #02  pc 000459e6  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
DEBUG(1700):          #03  pc 00011cb4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #04  pc 0003c3d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #05  pc 00023cb4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #06  pc 0001c244  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #07  pc 0005155a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #08  pc 00058faa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #09  pc 00016c78  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #10  pc 0001d35c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #11  pc 0001c1f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #12  pc 000513c8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #13  pc 0003ec58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG(1700):          #14  pc 0002e908  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
DEBUG(1700):          #15  pc 0002f7be  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
DEBUG(1700):          #16  pc 00008c86  /system/bin/app_process
DEBUG(1700):          #17  pc 0000d362  /system/lib/libc.so
DEBUG(1700): code around pc:
DEBUG(1700): afd0f0f0 1a00002b e88d0fe0 e2603000 e213301c 
DEBUG(1700): afd0f100 0a00000a e1530002 8202301c e1b0ce03 
DEBUG(1700): afd0f110 28b100f0 48b10300 28a000f0 48a00300 
DEBUG(1700): afd0f120 e3130004 1491a004 1480a004 e0422003 
DEBUG(1700): afd0f130 e2522020 3a000008 e3c1c01f e28cc040 
DEBUG(1700): code around lr:
DEBUG(1700): a8119b68 2a006063 1c38d00e ee7cf7f5 28006160 
DEBUG(1700): a8119b78 200cd103 61204240 1c29e086 f7f51c3a 
DEBUG(1700): a8119b88 6965ee60 686a61a5 886b61e2 d8014293 
DEBUG(1700): a8119b98 d90a42ba 4a3f493e 18712005 686e18b2 
DEBUG(1700): a8119ba8 96009701 ee70f7f5 1c27e063 372418ab 
DEBUG(1700): stack:
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3a8  00000000  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3ac  beebc3f8  [stack]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3b0  00000000  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3b4  afd103f0  /system/lib/libc.so
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3b8  00000003  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3bc  afd41724  /system/lib/libc.so
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3c0  46a95008  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3c4  c0000000  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3c8  beebc460  [stack]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3cc  4166ebc0  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3d0  416ae1c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3d4  afd0c741  /system/lib/libc.so
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3d8  00000000  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3dc  afd103f0  /system/lib/libc.so
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3e0  df002777  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3e4  e3a070ad  
DEBUG(1700): #00 beebc3e8  00000000  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3ec  a8125a48  /system/lib/libutils.so
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3f0  0011ce24  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3f4  beebc460  [stack]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3f8  4166ebc0  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc3fc  416ae1c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
DEBUG(1700):     beebc400  4166ebbc  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc404  46a95008  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc408  0013e8f0  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc40c  a8119b8b  /system/lib/libutils.so
DEBUG(1700): #01 beebc410  000a8b90  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc414  1fe0106c  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc418  00000001  
DEBUG(1700):     beebc41c  0013e248  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc420  ad3780f8  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
DEBUG(1700):     beebc424  0000aaa0  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc428  0013e8f0  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc42c  0013e248  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc430  ad3780f8  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
DEBUG(1700):     beebc434  0000aaa0  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc438  0013e8f0  [heap]
DEBUG(1700):     beebc43c  ad3459e9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
ActivityManager(124): Process com.mypackage.MyApplication (pid 2798) has died.
```

The problem seems to happen because this device only has a 22mb (?) heap size allocated. When reading `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`, `.totalMemory()`, and `freeMemory()`, I get 22mb, 2mb, and 0.5mb (respectively). Because apparently there's only 0.5mb "free", it can't parse the ~0.5mb XML file.

(When testing that on my other test device, I get 32mb, 5mb, and 2mb.)

My question is: is there any way to load this XML without crashing the application like that?

Incidentally I have some memory-intensive bitmaps manipulation on the application, but that doesn't throw any error... it still manages to run under the 24mb limit. I'm having a hard time understanding why a simple XML parsing would give me so much trouble.

This is an unmodified ROM, stock commercial installation of that model.

I can properly parse other XML files, or even this XML file, as long as they're smaller. I had success  with a 190kb version of this file, for example.

I've read that the SIGSEGV errors may indicate a firmware issue. Still, it seems clear the problem is happening because it has no memory to parse the large XML I'd like to think of ways to circumvent this error altogether.

Comment: Do you have to use XML, or do you have the opportunity to use something else, like eg. JSON?

Comment: Changing the file schema/format at this point would be problematic since this project is already out and the XML is CMS-generated (and this is a sort of an edge case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML files that you want to use with `getXML()` are pre-parsed (thus loading it entirely into memory), so in your case I would suggest moving the XML to the `raw` folder, and reading it with SAXParser, which parses the xml as it reads it (keeping in memory only as much as you need for the current node).

Your Bitmap processing that you do is done natively, instead of in Java code, which allows for better memory management, and that's why you're not having problems with those.

Comment: Do you think there's a way to read a XML in /res/xml as if it's a "raw" resource? I tried `getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.myxml))` (seen in some examples) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, in the end I just moved everything to /res/raw. I wanted to keep things as they were as this app is already out, but it seems to work well and is a stable update. Thanks!